# How to re-populate Xamarin Picker based on previous selection from same picker?

Tags: xamarin.forms, picker

I'm looking to use a single picker in a hierarchy-based list. The idea is to select an item and based on this selection do the re-population of the same picker based on this selection using the data in the inner level.

The hierarchy may look like this

- List item A1

  - List item A1.1
  - List item A1.2

    - List item A1.2.1
  - List item A1.3
- List item B1

  - List item B1.1
  - List item B1.2
  - List item B1.3

I have done several attempts but I end up with an infinite loop in the SelectedIndexChanged method.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you need something like this.

```
<Picker x:Name="pick" SelectedIndexChanged="pick_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Picker.Items>
             <x:String>Hello</x:String>
        </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

And in code behind you use selectedindex to populate it.

```
private void pick_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pick.SelectedIndex == 0)
            pick.Items.Add("Hello_World");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

disable the `SelectedIndexChanged` method

```
// disable the event handler
myPicker.SelectedIndexChanged -= OnSelectedIndexChanged;

// update your Picker data

// re-enable the event handler
myPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += OnSelectedIndexChanged;
```